# How do I expand this function?

Tags: taylor-expansion

Can anyone help me to expand this function:

$$ f(\theta) = R \epsilon_0 \left(\frac{\ln{  (1+L/d \tan{( \theta )})}}{\tan{(\theta)}}\right)$$

I want to expand it for small $\theta$ (I guess around $\theta=0$).
Terms of order $\theta^2$ can be ignored.

I tried using a Taylor expansion, but it really took me nowhere. Can anyone help?

Comment: And there is no way to rewrite it or anything to give me something I can expand?

Comment: Note that $$\frac{\ln(1+ax)}{x}=\frac{ax-a^2x^2/2+a^3x^3/3+O(x^4)}{x}=a-a^2x/2+a^3x^2/3+O(x^3)$$ and $$\tan\theta=\theta+O(\theta^3)$$ hence $$ \frac{\ln(1+a\tan\theta)}{\tan\theta}=a-a^{2}\tan\theta/2+a^{3}(\tan\theta)^{2}/3+O((\tan\theta)^{3})=a-a^2\theta/2+a^3\theta^2/3+O(\theta^3)$$

Comment: Well I am allowed to ignore terms with $\theta^2$ or higher, but out of curiosity what is this big O ? And thanks btw.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation